# Android studio sqlite time 12:00 becomes 00:00

Tags: android, sql, database, android-studio, datetime

i am using datepicker inside my project and storing the date and time inside sql database. so my problem is that when i chose time: 12:13 and store it inside the database, i try to retrieve this time and i get 00:13 instead of 12:13.
**Only 12:00 ose not work**

**This is my format that I use to store:**

```
    SimpleDateFormat test =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss");
```

**And this is raw from my sql create table :**

```
work_time datetime NOT NULL
```

As you see this is datatime type, so any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: try hh instead of HH in HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

Humm... It seems that 00:00 means 12:00 in french time. This isn't a bug or problem, its the way its set.

Comment: Ok, So i open the database file and i saw that the time saved as 12:13, i think that my problem is when i retrieve the time, i need to format it back to 12.